# Update a bunch of relationships

Tags: apex

I have two entities CustomA and CustomB and a look up relationship from CustomA to CustomB.

I have a bunch of CustomA entities and want them all to point to the same CustomB object. So it is like:

```
List<CustomA> customAs = ... 
for (CustomA myCustomA:customAs) {
    myCustomA.CustomB__r = myCustomB;
}
upsert(myCustomA);
```

However, the relationship is not persisted. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`customB__r` is a reference to the customB object, but in order for that reference to exist, you need to point the fieldvalue of customA.CustomB__c to the Id of customB

Change your code to:

```
List<CustomA> customAs = ... 
for (CustomA myCustomA:customAs) {
    myCustomA.CustomB__c = myCustomB.Id;
}
upsert(myCustomA);
```